# Python Tkinter Toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter, window

I am working on a program that requires multiple windows, and the first one to appear is the login window, I used the Toplevel widget in order to make other windows its children, but this code keeps showing two windows instead of one.

```
from Tkinter import Frame, Toplevel
from ttk import Label, Entry, Button


class loginWindow(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.title("Title")
        self.frame = Frame(self)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.__make_layout()
        self.mainloop()

    def __make_layout(self):
        self.frame.user_name_label = Label(text="User name:")
        self.frame.user_name_text = Entry()
        self.frame.user_name_label.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.frame.user_name_text.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.frame.password_label = Label(text="Password:")
        self.frame.password_text = Entry()
        self.frame.password_label.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.frame.password_text.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.frame.login_button = Button(text="Login")# , command=self.__create_window)
        self.frame.login_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    win1 = loginWindow()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of the widgets created in `_make_layout` are created without a parent. This means they're children of the default root. You need to pass a parent to each of them, the same way you do to the `Frame`. Like this:

```
self.frame.user_name_label = Label(self.frame, text="User name:")
self.frame.user_name_text = Entry(self.frame)
# etc.
```

When I run your exact code, I don't get a second window, on any platform I try. The closest I get is on OS X, where an entry for the default root window appears in the Window menu, but the window itself still doesn't appear and the widgets all end up on the `Toplevel` (although not on the `Frame` where you wanted them). But it certainly would be legal for Tkinter to show a second window here, and put some or all of your widgets on it.

Answer (score 2):

This must be a platform dependent issue, since abarnert isn't having issues with multiple windows. I use OS X with XQuartz and the following code gives me two windows:

```
from Tkinter import Toplevel, Tk
Toplevel().mainloop()
```

However, this code gives me one window:

```
from Tkinter import Toplevel, Tk
Tk().mainloop()
```

I believe your first window should be declared `Tk()` and subsequent windows should be `Toplevel()`.

Comment: How do you even get Tkinter to compile for X11 instead of Aqua? That stopped working for me multiple versions ago…

Comment: I'm using Anaconda 2.7.

Comment: Crazy… anyway, I was able to duplicate this with a cygwin Python and X11 on Windows. So I guess the issue is that whatever Tkinter does to hide an unused main window works on Aqua and on Windows, and on at least one modern GNOME X11 system… but does not work on all X11 systems, maybe especially including funky ones like XQuartz or Cygwin that delegate some window management to the native window manager?

Comment: @abarnet, some distributors like MacPorts have supported building with X11 on OS X for quite some time.  And, as of 2.7.6 / 3.3.3 / 3.4.0, there are now standard Python `./configure` and `make` options to allow overriding the default Tcl and Tk header and lib locations; see http://bugs.python.org/issue1584.